# Парсинг логов Apache сервера в CSV. Вопросы по блокам

Tags: apache, логирование

Что содержит в себе столбец с данным содержением?

```
http-nio-3020-exec-70
ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]
http-nio-3020-exec-86
main
```

и

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
```